# Select element from Ajax html string with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, string, dom

I am building a new project and I'm trying to avoid the use of jQuery. I am using [Chibi micro-framework](https://github.com/kylebarrow/chibi) which seems very promising.

```
var container = $('#container');

$().ajax(some_address,'GET',function(data,status){

    container.html(data,'append');

});
```

The data from the Ajax return is a HTML string.
I want to select certain divs from inside the string (the string is giving back the whole html page).

In jQuery I would have done something like:

```
$('.select_this', data);
```

How can I achieve this? I believe this can (only?) be done with just javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html');

var elements = doc.getElementsByClassName('select_this');

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    alert(elements[i].innerHTML);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/t6w57/4/ for a working example.

**Edit:** For older browsers, you will need a polyfill (this code is adapted from [the DOMParser documentation by the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#DOMParser_HTML_extension_for_other_browsers)):

```
(function(a){var b=a.prototype,d=b.parseFromString;try{return(new a).parseFromString("","text/html")}catch(e){}b.parseFromString=function(a,b){var c;return/^\s*text\/html\s*(?:;|$)/i.test(b)?(c=document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(""),(/<!DOCTYPE/i.test(a)?c.documentElement:c.body).innerHTML=a,c):d.apply(this,arguments)}})(DOMParser);
```

*Non-minified code:*

```
/*
 * DOMParser HTML extension
 * 2012-09-04
 * 
 * By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com
 * Public domain.
 * NO WARRANTY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.
 */

/*! @source https://gist.github.com/1129031 */
/*global document, DOMParser*/

(function(DOMParser) {
    "use strict";

    var
      DOMParser_proto = DOMParser.prototype
    , real_parseFromString = DOMParser_proto.parseFromString
    ;

    // Firefox/Opera/IE throw errors on unsupported types
    try {
        // WebKit returns null on unsupported types
        if ((new DOMParser).parseFromString("", "text/html")) {
            // text/html parsing is natively supported
            return;
        }
    } catch (ex) {}

    DOMParser_proto.parseFromString = function(markup, type) {
        if (/^\s*text\/html\s*(?:;|$)/i.test(type)) {
            var
              doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("")
            ;
                if (markup.toLowerCase().indexOf('<!doctype') > -1) {
                    doc.documentElement.innerHTML = markup;
                }
                else {
                    doc.body.innerHTML = markup;
                }
            return doc;
        } else {
            return real_parseFromString.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
}(DOMParser));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am getting Cannot call method 'getElementsByClassName' of null

Comment: @Alvaro What browser are you using? What is the HTML string you're using?

Comment: Chrome. I am trying to create a jsfiddle. the HMTL string is the return data from the ajax call to a certain page, you mean this?

Comment: The jsfiddle is giving me the same error (with Chrome)

Comment: The fiddle works for me in Firefox and IE but not Chrome (I tried with no-plugins just in case)

Comment: @Alvaro See http://jsfiddle.net/t6w57/4/. It works fine for me with Mobile Safari.

Comment: The jsfiddle works now in Chrome. Thanks! But now Im wondering if this is the simpliest way to go.

Comment: Doens't seem to work in my function, I get the same error. I am fine with jQuery but not much with pure javascript. I am starting to think that what the ajax call returns is not exactly a string.

Comment: @Alvaro Try adding the code at the **beginning** of your JavaScript code.